# Compare two rows in the same table for equality of one column and inequality of another column combination in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following table in my database:

Table name: INSURANCE TABLE

```
ID | Policy | Lon | Lat

1  | 34564  | 2.0 | 4.0 

2  | 67548  | 1.1 | 1.4

3  | 34564  | 1.8 | 9.4

4  | 98271  | 4.3 | 2.3

5  | 90198  | 5.6 | 4.5

6  | 98271  | 1.3 | 5.6

7  | 90198  | 5.6 | 4.5

8  | 34564  | 2.0 | 4.0
```

I am looking for a sql query that will return a result set in the following manner:
The result set contains those rows which have a Policy value equal to atleast one other row, but the other row's value for the (Lon, Lat) combination should be different.

For the table above I should get the following result set:

```
1 | 34564 | 2.0 | 4.0 

3 | 34564 | 1.8 | 9.4

4 | 98271 | 4.3 | 2.3 

6 | 98271 | 1.3 | 5.6
```

I would appreciate responses on how to write this query.

Comment: `MySQL` or `MS SQL Server` ?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from insurancetable t
where exists (select 1 from insurancetable t2 where t2.policy = t.policy and t2.id <> t.id);
```

EDIT:

According to your question, the ids should be fine.  But you can use lat and long if you wish:

```
select t.*
from insurancetable t
where exists (select 1
              from insurancetable t2
              where t2.policy = t.policy and
                    (t2.lat <> t.lat or t2.lon <> t.lon)
             );
```

Comment: I don't want to compare the two rows id, but i want to compare the Lon and Lat columns. Please give me the query for that,

Comment: Modify the last And to: (t1.lat<>t2.lat or t1.lon<>t2.lon)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solve your problem.

```
 select min(t1.id) as id, t1.Policy, t1.lon, t1.lat from INSURANCE t1
 inner join INSURANCE t2 on 
     t1.Policy = t2.Policy and t1.Id <> t2.Id 
 where t1.lat <> t2.lat or t1.lon <> t2.lon
 group by t1.Policy, t1.lon, t1.lat
 order by id
```

min(id) to get first id in case of duplication. eg Id 1 and Id 8. it will get just the Id 1.